# Trouble in the process of modifying source code from python2 to python3

Tags: python, fonts

https://gist.github.com/medicalwei/c9fdcd9ec19b0c363ec1, the link directs to source code written in python2 which aims to apply faux bold algorithm to trutype(.ttf) files for generating new trutype(.ttf) files. It is not convenientto install python2 in my computer, so i intend to transfer the source code. In the process of modifying it, i failed to find the module named "generate_c_byte_array" either on Google or Pypi. What can i do under the circumstance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`generate_c_byte_array` is a module from what looks like the application you are trying to convert: https://github.com/MarSoft/pebble-firmware-utils/blob/master/generate_c_byte_array.py

There's the code for it, it's not something available as a library to install with pip.